# Refresh .js-file everytime I edit something in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I try to find a way to refresh my javascript-file automatically after I changed something in my typescript-file.

Comment: you can use [`browsersync`](https://www.browsersync.io/) or [`webpack hot-reload`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/)

Comment: the browsersync just change my current browser,(like when i change something in my css it automatically refresh the browser ) not my javascript-file.

Comment: solved it with hot-reloaded!

thanks for ur help